# Convergence/ divergence tests

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

If i split this equation to test for convergence/divergence, I get one part to be divergent and the other convergent. Can I say something meaningful about convergent + divergent = ? Or is there another way?

$$\frac{3}{\ln(n)}+\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln(n)}$$
$$\frac{3+(-1)^n}{\ln(n)}$$

Comment: Convergent+Divergent=Divergent

Comment: what's your original sequence? To split you usually have to prove absolute convergence first

Comment: In your example, both parts are convergent (and converge to zero) as $n$ approaches positive infinity. Did you mean something else?

Comment: @Christian original is the last 'function'. I left the sigma notation out. It goes to infinity and start with n=2. I think I wasn't supposed to split it then since conditional and absolute convergence is explained in another section.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** Note that
$$\dfrac2{\ln(n)} \leq \dfrac{3+(-1)^n}{\ln(n)} \leq \dfrac4{\ln(n)}$$

Comment: So 2/ln (n) is divergent, and since that is less than the original 'function'. The original function must be divergent?

Comment: @flux $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac2{\ln(n)} = 0$